# how to stop for child process result in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-modules, child-process

I was working on a code using python and node. I called python code using child-process in node js to use its outputs.

```
  var images_score = 0
  const python = spawn('python',[__dirname + "/car_detect/main.py", img_name]);
  python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    images_score = Number(data.toString());
    console.log(images_score);
  })
}

if (images_score == 1){
//some code here
}else{
console.log('err');
}
```

but before I receive the result (data.toString() == '1'), node continues the program without giving the output of my python code and shows me 'err' in the console.

Comment: Put `some code here` to `data` callback like `console.log(images_score);`

Comment: The `if (images_score == 1)` is executed immediately after you start the `python` subprocess, not when it has finished. You need to wait for that, and run the code when the child process ends.